# AttributeError: module 'torchvision.models.detection' has no attribute 'deformable_detr'

Tags: python

I have code for DEtection TRansformer (DETR) and here is a line of code that have problem:

```
detr = torchvision.models.detection.deformable_detr.DeformableDETR(num_classes=1)
```

Here also my frameworks:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.models import detection, mobilenet
```

But when i run, it showed the error as like the title

Because my project need to be done with DETR so that I want the deformable_detr can be work. Hope that some ones can help me

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you provided is creating an instance of the DeformableDETR model from the torchvision.models.detection.deformable_detr module with num_classes=1. This model is a variant of the original DETR model that includes deformable convolutional layers.

Regarding your imported frameworks, it seems that you have imported the detection and mobilenet modules from torchvision.models. The detection module provides various object detection models, including DETR and its variants, while the mobilenet module provides MobileNet architecture models.